# Python, printing multiple string lengths for strings within a list

Tags: python, for-loop

Using a for loop, how can a list generated by the input function display each string length in the order that they have been input?

example:

Please enter a list of numbers separated by a comma.
one,two,three,four,five
The length of the string one is 3.
The length of the string two is 3.
The length of the string three is 5.
The length of the string four is 4.
The length of the string five is 4.

Below is the code I have written so far. im sure it's laughable but i can't figure it out.

```
# stringList will contain a list of strings that have been entered.
stringList = input("Please enter a list of numbers seperated by a comma.\ne.g. Citreon,Ford,Audi,Mercedes\n")

i = 0

for i = 0:
  print(f"The length of the string {i} is {(len_stringList[])}."
  i += 1
```

I have tried to construct a for loop in order to display the strings in order, along with each strings length.

The string index number should be in text, with index[0] starting at 'one' up to the final user input (five in the example above)
Each string length should be displayed in a numerical value.

Comment: `input` never creates `list` objects. It always returns a `str` object

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to split the input string into a list, and then you can iterate over that list with a `for` loop and print the `len` of each element.

```
>>> for s in input("Please enter a comma-separated list: ").split(","):
...     print(f"The length of {s} is {len(s)}")
...
Please enter a comma-separated list: one,two,three,four,five
The length of one is 3
The length of two is 3
The length of three is 5
The length of four is 4
The length of five is 4
```

Comment: How could the the single quotes be removed from the output? 'one' becoming just one.

Comment: Remove the `!r`.